# adding accessing and deleting items from a python list

Tags: python

Learning lists and arrays and I am not sure where I went wrong with this program. Keep in mind I am still new to python. Unsure if i am doing it right. Ive read a few tutorials and maybe Im not grasping list and arrays. Ive got it to where you can type a name but it doesnt transfer to a list and then i get list is empty constantly as well as other errors under other functions in the code.

```
 def display_menu():
    print("")
    print("1. Roster ")
    print("2. Add")
    print("3. Remove ")
    print("4. Edit ")
    print("9. Exit ")
    print("")
    return int(input("Selection> "))


def printmembers():
        if namelist > 0:
            print(namelist)
        else:
            print("List is empty")


def append(name):
    pass


def addmember():
    name = input("Type in a name to add: ")
    append(name)

def remove():
    pass

def removemember():
    m = input("Enter Member name to delete:")
    if m in namelist:
        remove(m)
    else:
        print(m, "was not found")

def index():
    pass

def editmember():
    old_name = input("What would you like to change?")
    if old_name in namelist:
        item_number = namelist.index(old_name)
        new_name = input("What is the new name? ")
        namelist[item_number] = new_name
    else:
        print(old_name, 'was not found')


print("Welcome to the Team Manager")

namelist = 0

menu_item = display_menu()

while menu_item != 9:
    if menu_item == 1:
        printmembers()
    elif menu_item == 2:
        addmember()
    elif menu_item == 3:
        removemember()
    elif menu_item == 4:
        editmember()
    menu_item = display_menu()
print("Exiting Program...")
```

Comment: your `append()` is empty. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: yet it says append(name). just needing better clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starting out, you've got the right ideas and you're making good progress. The main problem is how you defined `namelist = 0`, making it a number. Instead, `namelist` needs to be an actual `list` for you to add or append anything to it. Also, you're `append()` method is not necessary since once you define `namelist` as a `list`, you can use the built-in `list.append()` method, without having to write your own method.
So here are a few suggestions/corrections, which once you have the basis working correctly, you should be able to work out the rest of the bug fixes and logic.

1. Since you don't have any main() method, you can define `namelist` on
   the **first line of code**, before any other code, so that it is
   referenced in each method:
   `namelist = [] # an empty list`
2. Change `addmember()` method to:

   `def addmember():
       name = raw_input("Type in a name to add: ")
       namelist.append(name)`
3. Since `namelist` is a list, we can use the `built-in` `len()` method on `nameslist` to check if it's empty when printing out its contents (if any):

   `def printmembers():
           if len(namelist) > 0: # Get the length of the list
               print(namelist)
           else:
               print("List is empty")`

Now that the `Add()` menu option is working for adding a name to the `namelist`, you should be able to implement removing, and editing names to the list using similar logic.

Comment: upon fxing my code in several places I have better functionality yet i get this error when trying to access the list.TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()

Comment: Which line gives you that `TypeError`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week4/.idea/Team Management.py", line 48, in <module>
    printmembers()
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week4/.idea/Team Management.py", line 14, in printmembers
    if namelist > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > int()

Comment: @JasonRay Thanks for the traceback info. I've added updated code in the answer, see #3, to fix that error

Comment: Thank you for explaining that as throughly as you did. I believe I understand accessing lists a whole lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider initializing the list to be empty instead of zero (unless you want that element).

```
namelist = list()
```

Also, your append method does not perform any actions. It's also pretty unnecessary since you can just use the append method of list.

```
def addmember():
    name = input("Type in a name to add: ")
    namelist.append(name)
```

If you did want to make your own append method you should understand that the variables in the function definition are inputs, so just saying `def append(name)` won't perform any action. In this case `name` is the identifier you are applying to the input argument. You could just as easily call it anything you wanted. A good way to understand this is by assigning the argument a different variable name than the one you pass it. Like this:

```
def append(nameToAppend):
    namelist.append(nameToAppend)
```

You can call your append method in addmember like this:

```
def addmember():
    name = input("Type in a name to add: ")
    append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting name from input, you call the append(name)  method, yet your append method doesn't do anything yet.

In your append method you have to add the name you get to your namelist, like how you do in the editmember method.